# Android Studio Log showing error while Running SQLite Command

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to create a database and a table to store my Card's details and then display it.
And I created this schema

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context context;
    private static String DB_NAME="CardsDetails.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION=1;
    private static final String table_name="my_cards";
    private static final String id="_id";
    private static final String card_num="Card Number";
    private static final String cvv="cvv";
    private static final String year="year";
    private static final String month="month";
    private static final String user_name="Name on Card";



    public MyDatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       
        String query= "CREATE TABLE "+table_name+" ("+id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+"card_num"+" TEXT, "+month+" TEXT, "+year+" TEXT, "+cvv+" TEXT, "+user_name+" TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+table_name);
        onCreate(db);

    }
    void addCard(String CardNo, String mon_, String year_, String cvv_, String name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(card_num,CardNo);
        cv.put(month,mon_);
        cv.put(year,year_);
        cv.put(cvv,cvv_);
        cv.put(user_name,name);
        long result=db.insert(table_name,null,cv);
        if(result==-1)
            Toast.makeText(context,"Input Failed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(context,"Card Saved Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

But, I am getting some errors and Exceptions on this code which i don't understand.
Here is the snippet from the log.

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "on": syntax error
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.antas.fingerprintauth, PID: 22200
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "on": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE my_cards (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, card_num TEXT, month TEXT, year TEXT, cvv TEXT, Name on Card TEXT);
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:986)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:593)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1850)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1773)
        at com.antas.fingerprintauth.MyDatabaseHelper.onCreate(MyDatabaseHelper.java:34)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:412)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
        at com.antas.fingerprintauth.MyDatabaseHelper.addCard(MyDatabaseHelper.java:45)
        at com.antas.fingerprintauth.AddDetails$1.onClick(AddDetails.java:60)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7218)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7187)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:817)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27629)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7707)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

And here is my Activity from which i am inserting data to database.

```
public class AddDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText card_num, cvv, yr, mo, user;
    int i = 0;
    Button saveBtn;
    ImageButton validate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_details);

        card_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cardnum);
        cvv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cvv);
        yr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.year);
        mo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.month);
        saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameCard);
        validate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.visibility);
        card_num.requestFocus();


        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               .setError("Enter Name on Card");
                }
                else {*/
                MyDatabaseHelper myDatabaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(AddDetails.this);
                myDatabaseHelper.addCard(card_num.getText().toString().trim(), mo.getText().toString().trim(), yr.getText().toString().trim(), cvv.getText().toString().trim(), user.getText().toString().trim());
            }

        });

      }
    }
```

Can Someone please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the sql statement using the values you defined in those constants. The value for your "name" parameter is "name on card" so when that gets substituted into your create statement you get illegal syntax since a table name cannot contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you when creating the database that the "username" variable you are passing is invalid.

try doing

```
private static final String user_name="Name_on_Card";
```

A Sql column cannot have spaces in the name.

**Edit**
I would advise you to not store any sensitive data such a credit card etc. in something that is easily accessible

Comment: I changed tha but still some errors are there:  2020-07-14 20:55:40.775 2787-2787/com.antas.fingerprintauth E/SQLiteLog: (1) table my_cards has no column named name
2020-07-14 20:55:40.778 2787-2787/com.antas.fingerprintauth E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting card_num=49555 cvv=55 name=brnhg year=45 month=565 from {P:2787;U:10386}
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table my_cards has no column named name (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO my_cards(card_num,cvv,name,year,month) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: You would also need to change `private static final String card_num="Card Number";` to `    private static final String card_num="card_number";

Comment: @Antas the error you've just mentioned is telling you, you are searching for a column named `2020-07-14 20:55:40.778 2787-278`

Comment: its actually column named name i edited question wrongly.

Comment: E/SQLiteLog: (1) table my_cards has no column named name
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting card_num=4885 cvv=556 name=studying year=85 month=566 from {P:3664;U:10386}
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table my_cards has no column named name (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO my_cards(card_num,cvv,name,year,month) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: @Antas remove and reinstall the app. By the sounds of it, you have altered the `static final` variables but you haven't updated/recreated your database

Comment: you are a life saver. Thanks a Ton

Comment: @Antas No problem, dont forget to mark the question as resolved.